# Removing duplicates from generic list

Tags: c#, linq

I defined an object, created an IEqualityComparer class for it, and used it like:

```
someList.Distinct(new DistinctComparer());
```

I thought this worked OK, but I was wrong. The comparer object specifies 11 properties of the object in the Equals method. I realized that the duplicates removed were random.

There is an additional property that I would like the removal based on, a Date. So for an object which had duplicates in the 11 properties, I would like to retain the object with the most recent date, the property of which is not included in the Equals method.

If it matters, the object is a US address as defined by the USPS. The Equals method:

```
      public bool Equals(Address x, Address y)
     {
        return x.HouseNo == y.HouseNo &&
           x.PreDir == y.PreDir &&
           x.StreetName == y.StreetName &&
           x.StreetSuffix == y.StreetSuffix &&
           x.PostDir == y.PostDir &&
           x.City  == y.City &&
           x.State == y.State &&
           x.Zip5 == y.Zip5 &&
           x.Zip4 == y.Zip4 &&
           x.Sud == y.Sud &&
           x.UnitNum == y.UnitNum;
     }
```

I do not know how to do have the address with the most recent sale date retained. Any clues? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So for an object which had duplicates in the 11 properties, I would like to retain the object with the most recent date, the property of which is not included in the Equals method.

In practice, `Distinct` will preserve (or rather, yield) the *first* of any equal values. So you can just order by date in reverse first:

```
var results = someList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
                      .Distinct(new CustomComparerWhichIgnoresDate());
```

This behaviour is not guaranteed, but I'd be shocked to see it change - it's the simplest, most obvious approach. (See [my Edulinq post on it](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/30/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-14-distinct.aspx) for more details.) Whether or not you're happy to rely on that undocumented behaviour is up to you - there's a lot in LINQ to Objects which *isn't* documented, but which I'd be pretty confident about relying on.

Comment: Nice one, but is this according to spec, or is this just a Distinct implementation detail (which can thoeretically change or may be different in e.g. Mono)?

Comment: Yes, many applications would break which MS almost never does. Also, there is no reason to change. I also rely on this.

Comment: I agree that there is no reason this would change. I'd just like to know if this is in spec somewhere.

Comment: @JakubJanuszkiewicz: As I said in the answer, this behaviour is not guaranteed.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I can see it now. I must had somehow missed it when I commented.

Comment: Sorry for being obtuse, Jon, but wouldn't I have to sort the list by the 11 properties and then descending date before using the distinct method?

Comment: @user1268114: Why would you need to do that? All you're trying to ensure is that for any two equal values, the one you want comes before the one you don't.

Comment: I am confused. Does LINQ perform the OrderByDescending and the Distinct simultaneously, or does it do the two sorts sequentially?

Comment: @user1268114: In practice it will actually sort everything before `Distinct` gets to look at any values. You can definitely *think* of the sorting happening first. So everything gets sorted by date (latest first), and *then* `Distinct` looks through, retaining only non-equal values (the first it sees for any group of equal values).

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, Jon. I'm trying it now, but with 600K addresses, it'll take a while.

Comment: @user1268114: It really shouldn't. That should be pretty fast. If it takes more than 10 seconds, I'd worry that something's not right. Are you sure your `GetHashCode` method is implemented properly? (It should mirror your `Equals` method, in terms of properties used.)

Comment: I think I need to re-evaluate my design. The address data comes to me in 30K addresses per file.

Comment: @user1268114: I'm not sure why that matters, unless you actually can't load all 600K into memory at the same time.